# Query fullCalendar dayClick - convert (date) to HH.MM

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I want the time will be selected when clicking on timeslot of a day in fullclendar. i.e, if i click on 9.00am - 9.30am slot, i want both time. this is my code:-

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            allDayDefault: false,
            dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view){
                popupopen = 1;
                var clickedTime = 'Clicked on: ' + date.format();
});
```

Now, if i click 10.00 am,this gives:- Clicked on: 2016-07-19T10:00:00. But, i only want,10.00. How to get that? And also when i click on 10.00 -10.30 slot, how to get both time?

Comment: there is a property to set the time format       timeFormat: 'H(:mm)' [link](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/timeFormat/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question: date is a `moment.js` object, so just use moment.js methods.

```
var clickedTime = date.format("h:mm a");
```

As for getting the second date, I can only think of setting it manually using `slotDuration` and then since you will know this value, you can add it to the start date.

E.g. in my calendar the slotDuration is 1 hour, so I would do `date.add(1, 'hours');`